# How to Secure Android Sqlite Database file

Tags: android

Can Anyone say me how to Encrypt android Sqlite database file.Someone said to use Commons-Digester to Secure.Is it works.Or SqlCipher could Help to Secure data.

Answer (score 0):

> Can Anyone say me how to Encrypt android Sqlite database file

If your objective is to allow the user to encrypt their data via a user-supplied passphrase, use [SQLCipher for Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/).

> Someone said to use Commons-Digester to Secure

That is not very practical. You would have to decrypt the entire database before using it, then ensure that you re-encrypt the database when you are done using it. Not only is that difficult to ensure, but you have an unencrypted database on the disk in the meantime.